# Filling out form in Perl with the WWW::Mechanize module

Tags: perl, mechanize, www-mechanize

I am creating a script that logs into a web form in Perl using the mechanize module, and I'm getting the error:

> syntax error at /home/arty/scripts/gmail_pw_chngr.pl line 18, near "button"
> Execution of /home/arty/scripts/gmail_pw_chngr.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

#### Code

```
    use WWW::Mechanize;
    my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();

    my $url = "https://accounts.google.com/Login";

    $mech->get($url);

    $result = $mech->submit_form(
        form_name => 'gaia_loginform', # Name of the form
        #Instead of form name you can specify
        #form_number => 1
        fields       =>
        {
            Email  => 'arty32l@gmail.com', # Name of the input field and value
            Passwd => 'password',
        }
        button    => 'signIn' # Name of the submit button
    );
    print $result->content();
```

Above is the code, all the values from the input are the name, but it always errors on the same line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error in question is the missing comma before `button`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. They would help you.

Comment: `use strict` and `use warnings`, while generally excellent recommendations for avoiding hard to detect run-time errors, would be little value here as the OP already has a compile-time error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
use CGI qw(:standard);
use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);

use WWW::Mechanize;
    my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();

    my $url = "https://accounts.google.com/Login";

    $mech->get($url);


    $result = $mech->submit_form(
    form_name => 'gaia_loginform', #name of the form
    #instead of form name you can specify
    #form_number => 1
    fields      =>
    {
     Email    => 'arty32l@gmail.com', # name of the input field and value
     Passwd    => 'password',
    }
    ,button    => 'signIn' #name of the submit button
    );

     print $result->content();
```